# Remove brackets in V8 prepareStackTrace

Tags: node.js

I am working on reformatting stack traces in Node using `prepareStackTrace`. It evidently (node 18+) encases the return value in square brackets. I was able to use the backspace unicode to remove first one but no success with last. Suggestions and ideas why this was done? it's not just the stack trace that this function handles but also the error name so everything is encased in brackets.

```
Error.prepareStackTrace = (err, stack) => {
  return 'foo'
}
```

`console.log(err)` prints the stack as:

```
[foo]
```

You'll notice that you lost the name and message as well which is weird for a function called stack trace. It has to be re-added manually but thats workable though the entire thing is still in brackets.

Heres a sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-visvesvaraya-9dokms?file=/src/index.js - look at terminal output.

Comment: I see no brackets: after `Error.prepareStackTrace = function(err, stack) { return "foo"; }`, when I do `new Error("").stack` I get `'foo'`. Node 18.13. Please specify what you're doing differently.

Comment: @jmrk console log the error

Answer (score 0):

First observation: this seems to be an oddity of the Node `console` implementation. V8 on its own (in the form of the `d8` shell) behaves differently, and even the Node REPL behaves differently.

Second observation: `console.log(new Error("...").stack)` prints `foo` without square brackets.